# Error en angular 10 not defined a pesar de que defino los campos

Tags: angular, typescript

Eatoy recibiendo este error en Angular 10 al ejecutar mi app:

```
TypeError: this.datosTurno is undefined
    TurnosService turnos.service.ts:13
    TurnosService_Factory main.js:452
    Angular 6
    TurnosComponent_Factory turnos.component.ts:11
    Angular 5
    AppComponent_Template app.component.html:4
    Angular 20
```

Sin embargo tengo aparentemente todo bien definido:

- Interfaz:

```
export interface Turnos{
  /* Datos de los turnos */  
  jugador: number;
  textoTurno: string;
  jugador2: TipoOponente;
  ganadasJ1: number;
  ganadasJ2: number;
}

export enum TipoOponente{
    /* Tipo de Oponente: humano o máquina */
    humano,
    maquina
}
```

- Turnos.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Turnos, TipoOponente } from '../interfaces/turno.interface'; 

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TurnosService {
  datosTurno: Turnos;

  constructor() {
    /* Inicialización del componente (antes de renderizarlo) */
    this.datosTurno.jugador = 1;
    this.datosTurno.textoTurno = "Jugador 1";
    this.datosTurno.jugador2 = TipoOponente.humano;
    this.datosTurno.ganadasJ1 = 0;
    this.datosTurno.ganadasJ2 = 0;
  }  

}
```

- Turnos.component.html:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-row justify-content-between texto">
        <label class="col-2" for="turno">Turno de</label>
        <input class="col-2 form-control" type="text" id="turno" readonly
               [value]="turnosService.datosTurno.textoTurno">
        <label class="col-2" for="marcas">Partidas ganadas</label>
        <input class="col-2 form-control" type="text" id="marcas" readonly 
               [value]="0-0"> 
    </div>
</form>
```

¿Veis alguno algo que se me haya pasado? Le he dado mil vueltas y no sé donde está el error.

Cuando lanzo el servidor de prueba no me está generando ninguno de los componentes. Sólo aparece el error que muestro en esta pantalla, no muestra ningún otro tipo de error ni en consola ni en el terminal de angular.

He comprobado que en el app.component están incluídas las etiquetas. Me estoy volviendo loco..

Gracias,

Answer (score 0):

Después de mucho probar, he visto que cuando se ejecuta el constructor no tiene disponible la interfaz que he importado. Importo ngOnInit y hago dentro de este las asignaciones, funcionando ya todo perfectamente.

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en el constructor de tu servicio, ya que intentas acceder a una instancia que no existe, es `undefined`. La solución es crear la instancia cuando vas a rellenarla:

```
export class TurnosService {
  datosTurno: Turnos; //se declara pero es undefined

  constructor() {
    // Creamos la instancia cumpliendo la interfaz
    this.datosTurno = {
      jugador : 1,
      textoTurno : "Jugador 1",
      jugador2 : TipoOponente.humano,
      ganadasJ1 : 0,
      ganadasJ2 : 0
    };
  }  

}
```